# Word Automation Services - job failed with error 131172

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-office, word-automation-service

We are facing a problem with Word Automation Services in Sharepoint 2010. We have a workflow, which queues a conversion job (docx to pdf). In our dev environment, everything works well, but in production, a strange error occurs. No error shown anywhere, but file is simply not created. The only diagnostics is, that it puts error number 131172 to Items table in Word Automation Services database.

Nothing goes to SP log (log level set to information) and nothing to event log. Our error number is not listed in documentation. Timer is up and running..

Piece of code which queues job (nothing very special):

```
ConversionJobSettings jobSettings;
ConversionJob pdfConversion;
string wordFile;
string pdfFile;

jobSettings = new ConversionJobSettings();
jobSettings.OutputFormat = SaveFormat.PDF;
jobSettings.MarkupView = MarkupTypes.Text;

pdfConversion = new ConversionJob("Word Automation Services", jobSettings);

pdfConversion.UserToken = web.CurrentUser.UserToken;

pdfConversion.AddFile(wordFile, pdfFile);
        
pdfConversion.Start();
```

Have anyone seen this kind of error?

Comment: Hi Jan, is that error number correct? It doesn't show up in the official table: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512774(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Hi Arjun, yes, I double checked it and it is correct. 131172 is not listed in the table - and this is why I am wondering what error means.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem on Czech version of SharePoint 2019, which was resolved by installing English language pack.